# searching an element in list in ocaml

Tags: ocaml

```
(* function for union of two ordered sets*)
let rec search n list1 = match list1 with
    [] -> false
    | head :: tail when head = n -> true
    | head :: tail when head != n -> search n tail
;;

(* function calls and output *)
Printf.printf("\nList = {");;
open Printf
let list1=[3;1;2;4];; (* Input first set here *)
let () = List.iter (printf " %d ") list1;;
printf("}");;

n=2;;
let u = search n list1;;
```

I am getting an error:

```
File "search.ml", line 15, characters 0-1:
Error: Unbound value n
```

Line 15 => "n=2;;"

Kindly inform whether it is a syntactic error or otherwise and possible remedy as well. Implementation is done on linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expression `n=2` compares `n` to `2`, however `n` is not defined yet, so you get an error. You should use `let n = 2` to bind values to names.

Answer (score 1):

in OCaml to bound a value with a name one should use `len name = value` syntax